# Log the error for a whole && chain of commands (in Cron jobs)

Tags: shell, cron, logs, stderr

In one of my cronjobs, I have a long `&&`-chained command, at the end of which, I put `2>>/home/myparadise/public_html/wp-content/uploads/import/files/raytheon/raytheon_log_error.txt` - indicating that I want any errors to go to the file `raytheon_log_error.txt`

```
cd /home/myparadise/public_html/wp-content/uploads/import/files/raytheon && wget "https://www.raytheonsystems.com/test" -O raytheon_direct.zip && unzip -q raytheon_direct.zip && rm -f raytheon_direct.zip && csvjoin --left -c "MANUFACTURER SKU,MPN" $(ls -Art ASH* | tail -n 1) /home/myparadise/public_html/wp-content/uploads/import/files/raytheon/raytheon2_multi_images_only.csv > raytheon_new_joined.csv && wget -q -O - "https://www.myparadise.com.au/wp-load.php?import_key=XXXX&import_id=111&action=trigger" 2>>/home/myparadise/public_html/wp-content/uploads/import/files/raytheon/raytheon_log_error.txt
```

However, I never receive errors to that file.  Now, I'm not 100% sure what errors I'm expecting, but it stands to reason that since the last command is never executed, that *something* failed along the way.
*(Edit: I have subsequently discovered the error was permissions-related: `raytheon_direct.zip: Permission denied` - however, the question still pertains because I want any such and all errors otherwise, to be logged in future.)*

How do I fix this, so that if one of the `&&` command blocks fail, then that will be logged as an error to `raytheon_log_error.txt`, with specific causes included?

Comment: You could wrap the chain in a subshell or command group, and redirect the stderr of that

Comment: @steeldriver this sounds promising.  Perhaps you could post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the chain in a subshell or command group, and redirect the error stream of that:

```
(cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3) 2>>/path/to/errorfile
```

or

```
{ cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3; } 2>>/path/to/errorfile
```

For example

```
$ crontab -l | tail -1
* * * * * { date && touch /root/file && date; } 2>> ~/cron.log

$ tail cron.log
touch: cannot touch '/root/file': Permission denied
touch: cannot touch '/root/file': Permission denied
touch: cannot touch '/root/file': Permission denied
```

Alternatively (and perhaps for better readability) you could move the commands to a script.

Comment: Is there a reason why `Permission denied` errors would not get logged?  You can simulate the issue by having the user-executed script perform some file operation on a root-owned folder.  See that any Permission denied errors don't get sent to log?

Comment: @ptrcao I cannot reproduce that issue

Comment: I figured it out - it was a bit silly, because I was sending stderr output straight into the very folder that was permission-denied in the first place, so the logging action itself was also denied permissions lol.  So putting that extraneous hiccup aside, your answer is correct.  I shall accept.